# при длительной работе падает fps, даже без нагрузки

Tags: nvidia, intel, fps

Я недавно заметил, что при длительной, беспрерывной работе ноутбука частота кадров снижается до 26, при этом загруженность видеокарты и процессора ниже 30%. Температуру можно увидеть на скриншотах. В чем может быть дело?

P.s на зарядке и без таже фигня, даже закрыл Android Studio, реакции НУЛЬ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня похожий провал был из-за профилей энергопотребления. Причем в нескольких местах в Винде пришлось их найти и поставить на "макс. производительность".

Comment: а где ты эти профили нашел?

Comment: Попробуй правой по иконке батареи в трее - Центр Мобильности Windows.

Comment: кстати, fps снижается после работы ноутбука с тяжёлой игрой - cyberpunk 2077, как пример, ну или я просто виртуалок больше 3-4 запустил. После того как вернул ноуту утерянную плашку оперативки, fps снижаться стало на 46, вместо 26. Центр мобильности вообще никогда не открывал - лол. Поставил на высокую производительность, посмотрим как пойдет